# how to remove last 3 data in python from a doc

Tags: python

I've been attempting for a while to make it so that my quiz will delete data which had been done by the specific person 3 times ago. so if there is 4 people who have done the quiz and one of them is doing it for the forth time, I want it to delete the first time, this is the coding I have got so far

its not all of it, but you can see what I am doing

```
else:
    print(" ")
    print("Well Done",name,"!")
    print("Thankyou for taking this quiz")
    print("Your Score is ",finalscore,"/ 10.")
file=open(classname".txt", 'a')
file.write(str(name + " "))
file.write(str(finalscore))
file.write(str(":""\n"))
file.close()
print("Do you wish to view people's previous results?")

previousscore=input()
if previousscore=="yes".lower():
    sorter=input()
    if sorter=='1':
    reader=csv.reader(open(classname".txt"),delimiter=':')
    with open(classname".txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in sorted(f):
            print(line, end='')
```

I've only got it so far that it puts it into alphabetical order perfectly, but I need it to delete data.
The data shows up like this in the document;
Keanu 10:
Keanu 10:
Keanu 10:
Jack 7:
Jack 3:
Jack 3:
Harry 10:
Harry 8:
Jordan 7:
Jordan 10:
Keanu 1:

The python coding then changes it to this;
Harry 10:
Harry 8:
Jack 3:
Jack 3:
Jack 7:
Jordan 10:
Jordan 7:
Keanu 10:
Keanu 10:
Keanu 10:
Keanu 1:
Keanu 1:

But I want it to look like this;
Harry 10:
Harry 8:
Jack 3:
Jack 3:
Jack 7:
Jordan 10:
Jordan 7:
Keanu 10:
Keanu 10:
Keanu 2:

so it only shows the last three attempts :)
any help will be so helpful, but keep in mind I have only just started python... so don't get too technical ;)

Comment: If you want to store and retrieve this kind of data, while being able to delete easily, it's better to use a relational database to store your data. Something like SQLite could be a lightweight solution suitable for you.

A flat text file becomes unwieldy. Since you are opening the file in mode "a" (append), you will only ever append to the file. If you really want to stay with using text files, you will have to read the entire file into memory each time, and then add your result, delete the one you want to remove, and finally write everything back to the file.

Comment: So could we be able to do this? or would it be too difficult, either way, I have to do it with python ;)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like a class assignment. So my advice to you would be this:

1. Read the lines of text from the file.
2. Determine the name (key) from the line.
3. Add the score to a dictionary of lists. `d[key] = list(score, score, score, ...)`
4. Shorten the list if it's too long.

After that, you'll have the "most recent" scores for each player in a list by that player's name. You can sort however you like.